# Keep a PHP script running indefinitely on a Web Server

Tags: linux, php, nohup

I'm having a pretty big issue that I need to get resolved. Basically I have little experience using `Linux` and I've been working on a project recentley that involves me having to use quite a lot of `Linux` commands to run `php scripts` on my web server.

Basically I've two scripts

1. get_tweets.php
2. parse_tweets.php

I need these to be running constantly for the next 3 - 4 weeks on my web server. I use the following command to get them to run and they seem to last for the day but when I check in the morning they seem to have stopped working!

`nohup php get_tweets.php > /dev/null &` and then
`nohup php parse_tweets.php > /dev/null &`

I know that by using `&` I can keep the scripts running in the `background` and they run when I log out of `ssh` but like I said they seem to run fine all day then when I check in the morning they've stopped.

The issue I am having is how I can keep them running non stop. Is there a simple `script` I could write to check if they are running and if not then restart them or perhaps restart them every 5 hours or something?

I'd appreciate any help guys as this is quite a big issue and I've got no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: If you would not redirect the output to /dev/null but to a file, you might find an indication on **why** they stop running and then remedy the cause for that. That is always a better approach in solving these kind of problems

Answer (score 3):

Put an endless loop around it:

```
nohup sh -c 'while true; do php get_tweets.php; done' >/dev/null &
nohup sh -c 'while true; do php parse_tweets.php; done' >/dev/null &
```

It might be useful to redirect the output to a real file (use >> to append instead of overwrite) so that any output can be checked to give you a clue why the script stops. Also check nohup.out for any clues.

Comment: This is working put they still switch off in the night...